# How to handle data composition and retrieval with dependencies in Flux?

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to handle a quite commons situation in medium complex apps using Flux architecture, how to retrieve data from the server when the models that compose the data have dependencies between them. For example:

An shop web app, has the following models:

- Carts (the user can have multiple carts)
- Vendors
- Products

For each of the models there is an Store associated (CartsStore, VendorsStore, ProductsStore).

Assuming there are too many products and vendors to keep them always loaded, my problem comes when I want to show the list of carts.

I have a hierarchy of React.js components:

- CartList.jsx

  - Cart.jsx

    - CartItem.jsx

The CartList component is the one who retrieves all the data from the Stores and creates the list of Cart components passing the specific dependencies for each of them. (Carts, Vendors, Products)

Now, if I knew beforehand which products and vendors I needed I would just launch all three requests to the server and use waitFor in the Stores to synch the data if needed. The problem is that until I get the carts and I don't know which vendors or products I need to request to the server.

My current solution is to handle this in the CartList component, in getState I get the Carts, Vendors and Products from each of the Stores, and on _onChange I do the whole flow:

[image: Data Flow]

This works for now, but there a few things I don't like:

1) The flow seems a bit brittle to me, specially because the component is listening to 3 stores but there is only entry point to trigger "something has changed in the data event", so I'm not able to distinguish what exactly has changed and react properly.

2) When the component is triggering some of the nested dependencies, it cannot create any action, because is in the _onChange method, which is considering as still handling the previous action. Flux doesn't like that and triggers an "Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.", which means that I cannot trigger any action until the whole process is finished.

3) Because of the only entry point is quite tricky to react to errors.

So, an alternative solution I'm thinking about is to have the "model composition" logic in the call to the API, having a wrapper model (CartList) that contains all 3 models needed, and storing that on a Store, which would only be notified when the whole object is assembled. The problem with that is to react to changes in one of the sub models coming from outside.

Has anyone figured out a nice way to handle data composition situations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible in your application, or the right way, but I had a similar scenario and we ended up doing a pseudo implementation of Relay/GraphQL that basically gives you the whole tree on each request. If there's lots of data, it can be hard, but we just figured out the dependencies etc on the server side, and then returned it in a nice hierarchical format so the React components had everything they needed up to the level where the call came from.

Like I said, depending on details this might not be feasible, but we found it a lot easier to sort out these dependencies server-side with stuff like SQL/Java available rather than, like you mentioned, making lots of async calls and messing with the stores.

Comment: I agree, but my problem is I have no control over the serve API, and it just handles basic models. I ended up doing the composition in the API and for now works nicely. Just have to be careful with updates to trigger the dependencies reload only when needed

Comment: Implementing a technology which few have seen, Relay/GraphQL are facebook buzzwords isn't a solution to anyone's problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I kind of disagree @Rollo Although there haven't been any implementation details, Relay/GraphQL is pretty well defined conceptually. Perhaps me referencing them wasn't a great choice, but the idea of allowing the lowest level component in a hierarchy to query for the entire data tree required to represent the app up to that level seems like a pretty reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Well if it helped you, all the power to you. But if you have a flat API, I think it's better to have encapsulated components that perform their own actions to retrieve data, it works better with what's already existing.

Relay/GraphQL isn't an easy pattern to implement.

Comment: No worries at all, it's a valuable discussion to have so I'm glad you brought our attention back to it...definitely still an interesting problem and I agree it's important to not jump onto the bandwagon before it's even left the station (in regards to GraphQL/Relay ) :P. Cheers!